# Why is NullPointerException thrown while using EasyMock

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, easymock

Below is my test code:

```
@TestSubject
MathApplication mathApplication = new MathApplication();

@Mock
CalculatorService calculatorService;

@Test
public void testAdd() {
    EasyMock.expect(calculatorService.add(10.0, 20.0)).andReturn(30.00);

    Assert.assertEquals(30.0, mathApplication.add(10.0, 20.0), 0);
}
```

The *CalculatorService* is an interface and it defines **add()** method which will be called in class MathApplication's add() method. 
As you can see, **EasyMock.replay()** is not called, so when I run the test class, the result is presented as :

> java.lang.AssertionError:  Expected :30.0 Actual   :0.0

What confues me is that since CalculatorService is not implemented, why there is no NullPointerException be thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EasyMock implements `CalculatorService` since you have annotated it with @Mock and are running in an appropriate EasyMock TestRunner (or Rule). However, since it's still in record mode while you are asserting, all methods will be legal, but they will return some junk default value, like 0 in your case.

Comment: I see, is CalculatorService implemented as an anoymous class like CalculatorService calculatorService = new CalculatorService() {
            public double add(double a, double b) {
                return 0;
            }
        };

Comment: Browsing the [EasyMock source code](https://github.com/easymock/easymock/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/easymock/internal/JavaProxyFactory.java#L30), for interfaces it uses [Proxy.newProxyInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance(java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class[],%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler))